# Vue 2 data returned by component data function are not defined

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I am developing an application and I am using `Vue 2` as my javascript framework, I tried to declare some `components` and use them in my `html` pages
this is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet"  
     href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.1/css/bulma.css"  />   
</head>
<body>

<div id="modal_element" >

<modal v-if="showModal" ></modal>

<button @click="showModal = true" >Show Modal</button>

</div>

<div id="root">
  <ul>
   <li v-for="task in incompeletedTasks" >
      {{ task.description }}
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.js" ></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>    
<script src="modal.js" ></script>
<script>
   let main_data = {
     tasks : [
        { description : "Go to the store ", completed : true },
        { description : "Leave the store" , completed : false }
       ]        
    }
   new Vue({
     el : "#root",
     data : main_data,
     computed : {       
       incompeletedTasks() {
        return this.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed);
       }
   }
 });
```

and this the `modal.js` file:

```
Vue.component('modal',{
  template : '<div id="modal_element">
          <div class="modal is-active">
          <div class="modal-background"></div>
          <div class="modal-content box">
            <p>
              Some Modal Text here ...
            </p>
           </div>
          <button class="modal-close" @click="showModal = false" >
          </button>
       </div>',

   data : function(){
     return {
       showModal : false
     };
   }
  });

 new Vue({
  el : '#modal_element',
 });
```

but the modal is not displayed, and I am getting the following error in the `chrome console`

```
   [Vue warn]: Property or method "showModal" is not defined on the instance        
    but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data 
    properties in the data option.
```

**Question**:
what modification do I have to make to get the code working? and html page successfully displays `modal`?

Comment: please put jsfiddle together with your code and I will work on it

Comment: also, the main div in component should not have the id of modal_element. it can make VueJS confused.

Comment: what is this part:    let main_data = {
       //some data 
   }
   new Vue({
      //Vue code here
   }); ?

Comment: @MU thanks for comments I didn't understand when you said `modal_element` shouldn't have set as the name of the element and it make `VueJS` confused, why `Vue` will be confused by this?

Comment: @MU I also provided the full codes in details please check it again thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a couple of things.

1. You are creating 2 vue instances in this example (#root and #modal-element), so the data will not be able to be shared unless you have some store.  Much better to have just a single instance and put components in that.
2. You will need to pass the component into the vue instance in order for it to be aware of the component.

Here is an example with alot of the stuff trimmed out.

https://jsfiddle.net/Austio/vhgztp59/2/

The gist of it is

```
var component = ...createComponentStuff

new Vue({
  ...otherVueStuff,
  components: [component]
})
```